# What is the algorithm or pseudocode that can loop through every possible combinations of an array of N dimensions?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, combinations

I need to generate an array of `NxN` dimensions where each value are binary with all possible combinations. What is the algorithm or the pseudocode that make it possible?

Here some case to understand the problem.

Generate an array of `N=2` dimensions:

```
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1
```

Generate an array of `N=3` dimensions:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

Generate an array of `N=10` dimensions:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
...
```

`N` is a variable. That algorithm depends on this.

A way to visualize this in a very simple way would be:

```
For each A1
    For each A2
        ...
            For each An
```

So, how can I do that?

Comment: There are two ways to achieve this: (1) generate the numbers 1 to 2^N and convert each on to binary and (2) use recursion.

Answer (score 0):

A simple recursion will suffice. If you know the answer for `n-1`, then for `n`, just double the array, and add `0` to the first copy and `1` to the second.